# Make a pixel transparent in QImage

Tags: c++, qt

I've got a problem with trying to make a part of the image transparent in Qt. This my code:

```
QImage myImage;
myImage.load("clouds.jpg");
cout << myImage.pixel(1,1) << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    for(int y = 0; y < 100; y++)
         myImage.setPixel(i,y,qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

But I still see the pictures but with a black rect on it. Not transparent.

Can someone help me?

Comment: avoid set pixel. It is really slow. Use `QImage::scanLine()` as the documentation suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the image format is not one which supports transparency.

I would try adding this code after loading:

`myImage = myImage.convertToFormat(QImage::Format_ARGB32);`